# NoClassDefFoundError when using class

Tags: oop, java

I am learning Java from scratch. I installed the JDK, and I got the Hello World Program running. I am trying to run a simple accountdemo program. In Account.java, I have :

```
public class Account 
{
    protected double balance;

    // Constructor to initialize balance
    public Account( double amount )
{
    balance = amount;
}

    // Overloaded constructor for empty balance
    public Account()
{
    balance = 0.0;
}

    public void deposit( double amount )
{
    balance += amount;
}

    public double withdraw( double amount )
{
            // See if amount can be withdrawn
    if (balance >= amount)
    {
        balance -= amount;
                    return amount;
    }
    else
            // Withdrawal not allowed
                    return 0.0;
}

    public double getbalance()
{
            return balance;
}
}
```

On compiling this, I got the Account.class. In accountdemo.java, I have this

```
class AccountDemo
{

 public static void main(String args[])
 {
 Account my_account = new Account();
 my_account.deposit(250.00);
 System.out.println("Current balance " + my_account.getbalance());
 my_account.withdraw(80.00);
 System.out.println("Remaining balance" + my_account.getbalance());
}


 }
```

On compiling this, I got AccountDemo.class. But, when I try to run this as an application, I get the error java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
C:\Users\roymustang/NT\Documents\javaprogram\accountdemo/java

I have set the classpath to : C:\Users\roymustang.NT\Documents\javaprogram

Am I missing anything obvious? Like mismatched uppercase or something?

EDIT : Not homework, just trying to learn.

I am using Textpad, http://www.textpad.com/ . It has an option run commands. So, I have configured it to run javac.exe (`C:\Program Files\SDK\jdk\bin\javac.exe $File $FileDir`)

and run as application by java.exe ( `C:\Program Files\SDK\jdk\bin\java.exe $File $FileDir`)

Comment: Go into Command Prompt, change to the directory containing the .java and .class files and invoke it like this: `java -cp . AccountDemo` and let us know what happens.  You have a mismatch in the paths above (roymustang.NT and roymustang/NT) which looks 'dodgy'.

Comment: Show us how you are compiling this.

Comment: Did you compile `Account` as well? In which directory are you executing the `java` command? Did you put your classes into packages (which are just not included in your post)?

Comment: When you say you have the Account.class and AccountDemo.class files, in which folder are these? How exactly are you trying to run it as a program?

Comment: doesn't recognize the option -cp

Comment: use -classpath instead of the non standard -cp

Comment: @DoctorRuss: They are all in the same folder javaprogram under My Documents. 
Thomas: How do I put into packages? Am I supposed to import anything?
Tudor:  Updated the question

Comment: @MisterSmith: I tried `C:\Users\jayanthv.NT\Documents\javaprogram>java -cp class AccountDemo.class` got an error : 
Error: Could not find or load main class AccountDemo.class

Comment: Yosh! you were right about -cp and -classpath, I had to put a space after the dot

Comment: should not be `-cp class`, should be `-classpath .`  Should not be `AccountDemo.class`, should be `AccountDemo`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi there I'll assume that you are trying to run this using no java IDE e.g. Eclipse or Netbeans.  I tested your code and they worked just fine.

> C:>java AccountDemo 
>   Current balance 250.0 
>   Remaining balance170.0

Your error Message is:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   C:\Users\roymustang/NT\Documents\javaprogram\accountdemo/java

meaning you used:

> java accountdemo

to run your program. Remember that Java is case sensitive this can be corrected by using this.

> java AccountDemo

Happy Coding ^_^

Comment: I keep getting "Error: Could not find or load main class AccountDemo"

Comment: 1) Try to recompile your AccountDemo.java ->
javac AccountDemo.java

2) Then use ->
java AccountDemo